# Parsing string with sscanf that has a string in it

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

Project is in C. I need to parse strings that are always formatted the following way: integer, whitespace, plus sign, multi-word string, plus sign, white space, integer, whitespace, integer, end-of-line

Example:
`10 +This is 1 string+ 2 -1`

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to enter in the formatting of sscanf so that the string surrounded by the '+' signs get parsed correctly, without including the + signs. Assuming sscanf can be used for this case.

I tried `"%d +%s+ %d %d"` and that didn't work.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `%s` but that reads up to the first white space character. You want to read a string of not-plus-signs, so say that's what `sscanf()` should do:

```
"%d +%[^+]+ %d %d"
```

That's a scan set — see POSIX [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html). You should also protect yourself from [buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/15168).  If you have:

```
char buffer[256];
```

use:

```
"%d +%255[^+]+ %d %d"
```

Note the off-by-one in the lengths — this is a design feature of the `scanf()` family of functions. You could skip leading spaces by putting a space after the first `+` in the format string. It is not possible to skip trailing spaces before the second `+` in the data; you'll have to remove those separately.

You ask for 'end of line' after the 3rd number.  That's fairly hard.  You might use:

```
"%d +%255[^+]+ %d %d %n"
```

passing an extra pointer to `int` argument to hold the offset of the last character parsed.  The blank before the `%n` skips white space, including newlines, so if you read into `int nbytes;` (passing `&nbytes`), then you'd check `if (buffer[nbytes] != '\0') { …handle trailing garbage… }` (but only after checking that you had four successful conversion specifications — `%n` conversion specifications are not counted in the return value from `sscanf()` et al).  There are other solutions to that; they're all grubby to some extent.

Comment: The way I read it the relevance of end-of-line is just what comes after the last integer, but I could be reading it wrong. Addressing it regardless adds additional learning for all.

Comment: It isn't clear what should happen if there is extra material after the third integer.  Ignore would be a possibility; gripe is another.  It's a reminder that input is often not as clean as you'd like or expect.

Comment: Ye old *"Hobson's Choice"* of answering on SO `:)`